# IncompleteReadError when reading file from S3 on AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

When reading a file from S3 on AWS Lambda I get `IncompleteReadError`. When I try it locally it works just fine. This is only happening on Python3.6 and works fine on Python3.7 - I need to use Python3.6 however. I also tried to use resource instead of client but got the same error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/function.py", line 141, in handler
    i = d.read()
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/response.py", line 82, in read
    self._verify_content_length()
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/response.py", line 134, in _verify_content_length
    expected_bytes=int(self._content_length))
botocore.exceptions.IncompleteReadError: 0 read, but total bytes expected is 36678.
```

The area of code where it fails is here:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')        
get_json_file = client.get_object(
    Bucket=os.environ['S3_BUCKET'],
    Key="{0}".format(file_name),
)

d = get_json_file.get('Body')
i = d.read()
data = json.loads(i)
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem, I guess the problem arises because of the large size of the stream. I used `_raw_stream` to solve this

Try doing this:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')        
object = client.get_object(
    Bucket=os.environ['S3_BUCKET'],
    Key="{0}".format(file_name),
)

raw_data = object['Body']._raw_stream.data.decode("utf-8")
data = json.loads(raw_data)
```

Comment: In my case, the `._raw_stream` returned an empty string.

Comment: I had the same issue, so as a workaround I downloaded the file from S3 to the Sagemaker Studio directory and then loaded it from there.